# how to get the tag of the UIImageView I'm tapping?

Tags: iphone, tags, uigesturerecognizer

i have several UIImageView, each of them has a tag; and I have an array of Images, what i want to do is: when user tap one of the UIImageView, the app give back the certain Image from array.

i implement like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) 
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*100 + i*15, 300, 100)];
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imageView.tag = i;

        NSLog(@"%d", imageView.tag);

        [scroll addSubview:imageView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(findOutTheTag:)];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    }

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 115*i);

}
- (void)findOutTheTag:(id)sender
{

    //  HOW TO FIND THE tag OF THE imageView I'M TAPPING?

}
```

I want find out the `imageView.tag`, and pass `imageView.tag` to

```
UIImageView *tappedImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageView.tag];
```

to display the image.

I did tag all of them, question is how I can find out the `tag` of the imageView I'm tapping? thank you for reading ^_^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the risk of making a recommendation without seeing the full picture of your app, why not use a custom UIButton instead of UIImageViews for this? With a UIButton you can setup an action and pass the sender id, from which you can easily access your tags and pull the data from your array.

OR if you really want to use the above code and your know for a fact the - (void)findOutTheTag:(id)sender method is being called, all your have to do is:

```
- (void)findOutTheTag:(id)sender {
    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)      
{
    case kTag1:
    //...
    case kTag2:
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: The sender here is the gesture recognizer so you actually have to do `switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)`.

Comment: +1 -(void)childTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{int tag = tapGesture.view.tag;} // worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a UIImageView why don't you use an UIButton. That way you can simply add a listener for UITouchDown events. You can tag each button so that in your touchDown method you can find which button was pressed.

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*100 + i*15, 300, 100)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    button.tag = i;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) controlEvent:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And inside of the touchDown: method you simply have to cast the sender to a UIButton in order to access the tag.

```
- (void)touchDown:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch(button.tag)
    {
        case TAG1:
           break;
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, DHamrick, I tried the UIButton instead of UIImageView, and it outputs the tag perfectly, did help me jump out my own thinking, but using UIButton may lead to implement lots of gestures to achieve other gestures like longPress and swipe i need to use, to move/delete the viewItem (also tag and array involved), it may become complex in my construction, since  UIGestureRecognizer already had them, i decide use them, anyway, thank you very much for your help, I'll send the app to you. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

To find out which image has to be touch ,use **touchBegan** method:

**Note:** First of all you need to confirm about image view should be `userIntrectionEnabled=YES;`
Now use this method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view].tag == 800) {

     //if image tag mated then perform this action      
    }
}
```

You can use switch statement inside **touchBegan**.