# Accessing tag value for UIImageView in UITapGesture Handler

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UITapGesture attached to an image view.  I'd like to reuse the same gesture across a couple of images.  To do that the handler method needs to be able to recognize from which image the tap is coming.  The method below attempts to access the tag value for the sender image view.  I based it on the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425059/549273.  However, I'm getting an error in the debugger that reads "unrecognized selector sent to instance".  I tried it exactly as written in the answer and I also tried it with the sender appended to the method as a parameter as shown below.  Netiher approach works.  Can someone show me what I did wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    topLeftImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [topLeftImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureView andSender:(id)sender {

    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"zero");
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"one");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the UIGestureRecognizer class reference:

> The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following
>   signatures:
>
> - (void)handleGesture;
> - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

Your method (`- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureView andSender:(id)sender`) does not conform to either signature.  Beyond this, when you create your gesture recognizer, you are using the action `@selector(handleSingleTap:)` which does not match up with this function, so it should never even be called.  Try this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    topLeftImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [topLeftImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureView {

    switch (gestureView.view.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"zero");
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"one");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Inafziger (as usual), but here's a better way to do it:  Place distinct gesture recognizers on the distinct views.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[topLeftImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

// just like first as far as the target and selector, but a distinct object
singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[bottomRightImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

// and so on ...
```

Now, the handler can just ask the gr to which view it is attached.  No tags, no switch statement.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr {
    UIImageView *theTappedView = (UIImageView *)gr.view
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was a good suggestion.  Personally I like the approach of using the switch statement over using distinct gesture recognizers.  But I can see why some people might like your approach better.