# Get identifier to which image tapped with dynamic images

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to find which image the user tapped using a gesture recognizer.
The scrollview as well as the image views are all created dynamically.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100)];

scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
int iPolaroidDimen = 200;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    UIImageView *polaroid = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconPol.png"]];

    polaroid.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin+(self.view.center.x/2)-(iPolaroidDimen/10), (self.view.center.y/2), iPolaroidDimen, iPolaroidDimen);
    [scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    polaroid.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [polaroid addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [polaroid setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [polaroid setAccessibilityIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"ImageView",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]];

    [scroll addSubview:polaroid];
```

The gesture recognizer

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Guess what?"
                                               message: @"An image was tapped"
                                              delegate: self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


[alert show];
}
```

Comment: use tags. This is what you need to do ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425041/how-to-get-the-tag-of-the-uiimageview-im-tapping

Comment: He needs a reference to the `UIImageView`--the view to which the gesture recognizer is attached. There's no need for tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *tappedView = gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a pointer to each of the 10 images so you can access them later. You only need to add tap gesture to the top view which has all the 10 images, and then add the following example code in your method (in which I give each image a different name such as cat, cow ,etc. :]):

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Guess what?"
                                                   message: @"An image was tapped"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


    [alert show];

    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect catRect = CGRectMake(self.cat.frame.origin.x, self.cat.frame.origin.y, self.cat.frame.size.width, self.cat.frame.size.height);
    CGRect cowRect = CGRectMake(self.cow.frame.origin.x, self.cow.frame.origin.y, self.cow.frame.size.width, self.cow.frame.size.height);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(catRect, point)) {
        NSLog(@"I am a cat!");

    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(cowRect, point)) {
        NSLog(@"I am a cow!");
    }
}
```