# Taking Bad-Access while Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to add gesture recognizer to UIImageView but taking a bad access.

```
[UISwipeGestureRecognizer openPhotoDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e589a0
2014-09-02 12:01:32.569 FotoTR[1949:669649] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISwipeGestureRecognizer openPhotoDetail:]: unrecognized    selector sent to instance 0x17e589a0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Here is my code;

```
  mainView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 408)];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];


    firstVerticalImageView = [[STGImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 153, 197)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPhotoDetail:)];
    [firstVerticalImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [firstVerticalImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainView addSubview:firstVerticalImageView];


    [mainView bringSubviewToFront:firstVerticalImageView];
```

What is wrong with this?

My openPhotoDetail method;

```
-(void)openPhotoDetail:(id)sender
{

PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoDetailViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoDetailViewController animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: please post your openPhotoDetail:  method

Comment: Does your openPhotoDetail method is in the same class than your UITapGestureRecognizer init ?

Comment: Where is openPhotoDetail method located?

Comment: Do you see `[UISwipeGestureRecognizer openPhotoDetail]` in your error log? That's your problem.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 i have seen this on error log once, now there is no error log, just bad-access

Comment: I haven't found any problems. I tried your code, it works fine. Something else is the problem. http://pastebin.com/zGnDYe4x

Comment: And I am talking about your crash log on top, in the question. It says `[UISwipeGestureRecognizer openPhotoDetail:]`. It should be `UITapGestureRecognizer` related.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 you are right, but i am not able to recognize the exception

Comment: When are you experiencing the crash? When you tap/scroll the scroll view, or when you tap the image view?

Comment: There might be something in `STGImageView` that is causing the crash. Convert that to simple `UIImageView` and see the output.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 I have changed STGImageView with UIImageView and got this exception -[CALayer openPhotoDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d54790

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60451/discussion-between-blackflam3-and-erdemgc).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
mainView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 408)];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];


    firstVerticalImageView = [[STGImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 153, 197)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPhotoDetail:)];
    [firstVerticalImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    firstVerticalImageView.tag=1;
    [firstVerticalImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainView addSubview:firstVerticalImageView];

[mainView bringSubviewToFront:firstVerticalImageView];


-(void)openPhotoDetail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer

    {

        // if you have tag value of your uiimageview ,you can get here like this try this code
    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
    int yourtag =theTappedImageView.tag ;
        NSLog(@"clicked");
 NSLog(@"yourtag item==%d", yourtag);


    }
```

Comment: have  you added delegate in your .h file @erdemgc

Comment: UISwipeGestureDelegation has nothing to do with adding the gesture.

Comment: can you change this line [mainView bringSubviewToFront:firstVerticalImageView].like this  [mainView addSubview:firstVerticalImageView];try let me know error @erdemgc

Comment: @Sport i have removed this line [mainView bringSubviewToFront:firstVerticalImageView] but still bad access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425041/how-to-get-the-tag-of-the-uiimageview-im-tapping try this

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code for tap gesturing.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPhotoDetail:)];
    [firstVerticalImageView addGestureRecognizer: tapGR];

    // Selector is something like this

-(void) openPhotoDetail:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Label tapped, your turn ...
    // Use gestureRecognizer parameter if you need the view tapped
    UIImageView *img = gestureRecognizer.View;
}
```

Comment: remove outlet linking for your image firstVerticalImageView and connect it again. clear code and try once again

Comment: it is not linked as outlet

Answer (score -1):

Your method is wrong , it should be like this -

```
 -(void)openPhotoDetail:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
 {

   PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController =
  [self.storyboard
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoDetailViewController"];

   [self.navigationController
   pushViewController:photoDetailViewController animated:YES];  

   }
```

Comment: The method itself is not being recognized. :)